# Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in

Tags: magento, boolean, member

I have used Magento Proto theme.

I have face one error in ajax response.

Fatal error : Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in  /app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php

Is there any solutions for fixed this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: please add all code responsible for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, There is a extension conflict problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Sam. I encounter exactly the same issue with Porto Theme. Could you tell me how exactly did you fixed the conflict? Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Comment: You just comment that code and check all things are working proper.
And all things are working proper.

(2) Check your extension model xml (app/etc/module) file. i think there is one or more xml file for any extension. So remove that file or rename and check

Comment: Hello Sam, Actually I am facing the same issue Fatal error : Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in /app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php  

but can't coment code actually I need this $viewpanel = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav')->toHtml(); for displaying selected filters.

Please suggest or provide answer, Thanking in advance